# moving files with xargs

Tags: bash, shell

I want to pipe the output of ls into head and pipe it into mv.

I used the following command on terminal but it isn't working properly.

```
ls -t Downloads/ | head -7 | xargs -i mv {} ~/cso/
```

Please do rectify the error. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why is it not working properly ? What is the expected and what is the actual result ?

Comment: That's a bad assignment. You shouldn't be piping the output of `ls` to *anything*, except maybe a pager like `less`.

Comment: Also, the first line of `ls`'s output is not a file name.

Comment: If you were using `zsh`, you could simply write `mv Downloads/*(om[0,7]) ~/cso`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use -I like here :

```
ls -t Downloads/* | head -7 | xargs -I '{}' mv '{}' ~/cso/
```

Comment: It isn't working.
The output is as follows:

    mv: cannot stat 'SingleCycleCPUDesign.pdf': No such file or directory    
    mv: cannot stat 'mips-assembly.tar': No such file or directory
    mv: cannot stat 'MIPS_Vol2.pdf': No such file or directory
    mv: cannot stat 'MIPS_Vol1.pdf': No such file or directory
    mv: cannot stat 'MIPS32_QRC.pdf': No such file or directory
    mv: cannot stat 'MIPS-Assembly.ppt': No such file or directory
    mv: cannot stat 'L06-SMIPS.pdf': No such file or directory

Comment: add the * after the `Downloads/` .. edited just now. And please mark it as an answer if it answers your query.

Comment: works perfectly fine now. Thanks a lot @Exception_al

Answer (score 3):

It is well documented that parsing `ls` output is not recommended. You can use this safe approach using `find + sort + cut + head + xargs` pipeline:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -printf '%T@\t%p\0' |
sort -z -rnk1 |
cut -z -f2 |
head -z -n 7 |
xargs -0 -I {} mv {} ~/cso/
```